# How to pull middle numbers from a string of numbers using regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex

I have a data field that contains large numbers in two formats:

```
553000.468...705.46.0000000        <- Format 1
553000.469.5501000.704.47.0000000  <- Format 2
```

I only need the three digits in the middle that include 703, 704, or 705

I was able to pull these digits by using regular expressions like so:

```
Regex num = new Regex(@"(?<number>7\d+) ?");
Match number = num.Match(numb);
if (number.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(num.Match(numb).Result("${number}"));
```

However, that only works if there isn't a 7 preceding the middle numbers

It seems to me that the best way to approach it would be to focus on the ".".  The problem is I can't figure out how to match character AFTER the "."  I can pull the numbers prior to the 1st "." by doing this:

```
Regex num = new Regex(@"(?<number>.\d+) ?");
Match number = num.Match(numb);
if (number.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(num.Match(numb).Result("${number}"));
```

This would give me everything prior to the period.  I'm using the cheat sheet found [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet) but it doesn't show how to match characters after the "."
If I can figure out how to do that then I can just repeat the pattern until I get to the numbers I need, then I can use the above code to get rid of the numbers after.  That may not be the most effective way to do it but I've never used regular expressions before and to be honest I find it very confusing.

EDIT:

I've been told I need to provide more examples or explain it better.  I have a database table with a column called Glsec.  This field contains numbers in two formats;  553000.468...705.46.0000000   and  553000.469.5501000.704.47.0000000 are examples of the two formats.

In the 553000.468...705.46.0000000 format I only need the numbers 703, 704, or 705 found in the first group of numbers AFTER the ... (14th character from the left)

In the 553000.469.5501000.704.47.0000000 format I only need the numbers 703, 704, or 705 found 4th group of numbers from the left (20th character).

The numbers in that group of three may contain any number between 000 and 999 but I only need the three numbers.  It is also possible that 703, 704, 705 can randomly pop up in the other groups of numbers so I have to make sure I am grabbing the numbers from the correct position.

I hope that explains it better.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "middle digits". Can you elaborate more on what you expect to match?

Comment: @MattHickford an example would be for the number 553000.468...705.46.0000000 I need to pull the 705 and for the number 553000.469.5501000.704.47.0000000 I need to pull the 704

Comment: BTW, who said `regex` is the best way to go with your problem?

Comment: @gdoron - I second your statement :)

Comment: @DavidB Middle digits prorbably wasn't the best term to use.  Sorry.  In the number 553000.468...705.46.0000000, I need to pull the number 705 and in the number 553000.469.5501000.704.47.0000000 I need to pull the 704.

Comment: @gdoron I would much rather use the Substring() method but this is how my boss wants to do it and since I'm only an intern i just say yes, sir. :)

Comment: @afuzzyllama. I saw people agree with that statement more than my answer, so I added it. `:)`

Comment: @Programming Newbie - well your job as a developer is to tell your boss that there are better ways/simpler ways to solve the problem.  Over complicating code isn't a good lesson to be learned.  Why don't you bring multiple solutions to him (`Regex()`, `Substring()`, `Split()`) and see what he has to say?

Comment: you could even perform some performance tests and show the results to your boss, recommending what you think is the best way to handle this problem.

Comment: afuzzyllama - Good point

Comment: @CarlWinder Yo also make a good point.  I think I'll do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the period as `\.`, as `.` means "any character" in a regular expression.

You can match a specific number of optional number + period before the number that you want:

```
Regex num = new Regex(@"^(?:\d*\.){3}(?<number>\d+)");
```

or after:

```
Regex num = new Regex(@"(?<number>\d+)(?:\.\d*){2}$");
```

Comment: Lookahead and lookbehind are waaaay overkill for this, and hurt performance.

Comment: @BenVoigt: There is no lookahead or lookbehind.

Comment: Oh, difference between `(?<=` and `(?<name>`.  Too much density of control characters.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method on the `.`?  Then you can get the number you want if it always has the same position or you can just loop through the array to find the numbers that you want.

Comment: +1 -- the problem appears to be that OP either wants the # that's between two values (703 & 705 inclusive) or the nth value in the list.

Answer (score 3):

> I only need the three digits in the middle that include 703, 704, or 705

You can use this:

```
@"\.(70[3-5])\."
```

If those are the only valid values.

**BTW, who said `regex` is the best way to go with your problem?**

Comment: @gdoron That would work until it came across a number that had those values included in the prior to where I needed them, which is a possibility.  for example, 553703.468...705.46.0000000 would give me 703 when in reality I need the 705

Comment: @ProgrammingNewbie. You should give more examples to what you need.

Comment: you could do then \.70[\d]\. which would guarantee only 3 digit number between 700 and 709 with a period before and after

Comment: `"\.(703|704|705)\."` might be better

Comment: @AustinSalonen. Used it with the other guy suggestion, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `String.Contains` to test for the three cases. Assuming the string is the variable `s`:

```
s.Contains(".705.")
s.Contains(".706.")
s.Contains(".707.")
```

Answer (score 1):

How about doing in in two steps.  First, find two periods with three digits in between.  Then, trim the periods.

```
Regex num = new Regex(@"\.\d{3}\.");
Match number = num.Match(numb);
if (number.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(number.Value.Trim('.'));
```

You may also capture a subset of the match:

```
Regex num = new Regex(@"\.(\d{3})\.");
Match number = num.Match(numb);
if (number.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(number.Groups[1].Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

The . is a meta character for Regular Expressions, so It will need to be escaped.  Is the number starting with 7 always 3 digits?

You can try the following:

```
   Regex num = new Regex(@"(?\.<number>\d+) ?");
   Match number = num.Match(numb);
   if (number.Success)
        Console.WriteLine(num.Match(numb).Result("${number}"));
```

Comment: In that position no, but 703, 704, and 705 are the only ones I need.

Answer (score 1):

If you get tired of regex....

```
    string[] formats = new[] {"553000.468...705.46.0000000", "553000.469.5501000.704.47.0000000"};
    var results = from format in formats
                  from sub in format.Split('.')
                  where new[] { "703","704","705" }.Contains(sub)
                  select sub;
```

Comment: Just seen your update so this won't be quite as helpful anyway!